# Error generating PDF with DomPDF with 5000 records

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

My controller, with DomPDF

```
public function exportPdf(){


    $facturas = Vale:: all();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.facturas', compact('facturas'));
    return $pdf->stream('facturas.pdf');
}
```

error:
**Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2097160 bytes)**

Any idea how to solve it ?  In small files of 10 sheets it takes but generates the PDF.  Thanks in advance for the help that you could give me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your application requires more memory than PHP is configured to have.

You could change this globally in your php.ini file, but in the case of these generators where only one function needs more memory, you can include an `ini_set();` in your code. That way, code that isn't expected to use lots of memory still gets cleaned up.

In this case, you would use `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` before your PDF code generation. You'll have to work out the right value to set based on available memory on your server, traffic you expect, etc.

Here are the relevant PHP docs:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit